# Quote from the Pirates of Carribean

Tags: articles, caribbean-english

Here's the scene. Jack and Angelica are in the captain's quarters on Black Beard's ship. They're both looking at a shelf full of bottles that have ships inside them. One of them contains Jack's ship named Black Pearl

Jack asks *"Why is the Black Pearl in a bottle?"*

Why does he say **a bottle**? It's quite clear for both of them which specific bottle the ship is in because they're looking at it when asks the question.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Why he uses the indefinite article rather than the definite, even though he’s referring to something they can both see?

Comment: _Why is it in THAT bottle?_ could indicate he is puzzled that it is not in another bottle. _Why is it in THE bottle?_ could indicate he was wondering why it was not in the closet.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for ELL.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He isn't asking why it is in that specific bottle. He's asking why it is in a bottle at all.